# Aligning the primary and secondary X-axis in StackPane XYChart in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8

How can I align the X-axis of two XYCharts in JavaFX 8 when I use StackPane? Problem arise when I set the second Y-axis to axis.setSide(Side.RIGHT) so that I have two Y-axis, one on the left and the other on the right.

Below is the sample code I am using:

```
 public class StackedPaneXYChartSample extends Application {

final NumberAxis axisPrimary = new NumberAxis();
final NumberAxis axisSecondary = new NumberAxis();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setScene(
            new Scene(
                    layerCharts(
                            createPrimaryChart(),
                            createSecondaryChart()
                    )
            )
    );

    stage.show();

}

private NumberAxis createYaxis() {
    final NumberAxis axis = new NumberAxis(0, 21, 1);
    axis.setPrefWidth(35);
    axis.setMinorTickCount(10);

    axis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(axis) {
        @Override
        public String toString(Number object) {
            return String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
        }
    });

    return axis;
}

private NumberAxis createYaxis2() {
    final NumberAxis axis = new NumberAxis(0, 51, 1);
    axis.setPrefWidth(35);
    axis.setMinorTickCount(10);

    axis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(axis) {
        @Override
        public String toString(Number object) {
            return String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
        }
    });

    axis.setSide(Side.RIGHT);
    return axis;
}

private LineChart<Number, Number> createPrimaryChart() {
    final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(axisPrimary, createYaxis());
    setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
    chart.getData().addAll(
            new XYChart.Series(
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                            new XYChart.Data(1, 1),
                            new XYChart.Data(2, 2),
                            new XYChart.Data(3, 8),
                            new XYChart.Data(4, 4),
                            new XYChart.Data(5, 7),
                            new XYChart.Data(6, 5),
                            new XYChart.Data(7, 4),
                            new XYChart.Data(8, 8),
                            new XYChart.Data(9, 16.5),
                            new XYChart.Data(10, 13.9),
                            new XYChart.Data(11, 17),
                            new XYChart.Data(12, 10)
                    )
            )
    );

    return chart;
}

private LineChart<Number, Number> createSecondaryChart() {

    final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(axisSecondary, createYaxis2());
    setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
    chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    chart.getData().addAll(
            new XYChart.Series(
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                            new XYChart.Data(1, 1),
                            new XYChart.Data(2, 2),
                            new XYChart.Data(3, 1.5),
                            new XYChart.Data(4, 3),
                            new XYChart.Data(5, 2.5),
                            new XYChart.Data(6, 5),
                            new XYChart.Data(7, 4),
                            new XYChart.Data(8, 8),
                            new XYChart.Data(9, 6.5),
                            new XYChart.Data(10, 13),
                            new XYChart.Data(11, 10),
                            new XYChart.Data(12, 20)
                    )
            )
    );

    return chart;
}

private void setDefaultChartProperties(final XYChart<Number, Number> chart) {
    chart.setLegendVisible(false);
    chart.setAnimated(false);
}

private StackPane layerCharts(final XYChart<Number, Number>... charts) {
    for (int i = 1; i < charts.length; i++) {
        configureOverlayChart(charts[i]);
    }

    StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
    stackpane.getChildren().addAll(charts);


    return stackpane;
}

private void configureOverlayChart(final XYChart<Number, Number> chart) {
    chart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    chart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
    chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
    chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false);
    chart.getYAxis().setVisible(false);


    chart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("overlay-chart.css").toExternalForm());

 }
}
```

I have tried to bind the two axes but still not resolving the problem, I guess am doing it all wrong. Please help, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the two charts to be stacked on top of each other or kept next to each other? Since your y-axis values are different, stacking doesn't make any sense to me, at least.

Comment: Yes, I want the two charts to be stacked on top of each other with the X-axis properly aligned.